# How to rename h2o POJO?

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, pojo, h2o

Using the following code in `python v2.7` on `UBUNTU 16.04` machine

```
model1=h2o.load_model('home/administrator/DeepLearning_model_python_1497342069792_59')
b=model1.download_pojo('.')
```

I can successfully create a `POJO` with name: `DeepLearning_model_python_1497342069792_59.java`

I want to change the name of the `POJO`,simply renaming the `POJO` will break the code.
How can I give a custom name while downloading the `POJO` itself?

Comment: I don't think we implemented model renaming yet, but when you are creating a new model you can set the desired name and the pojo should contain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace `DeepLearning_model_python_1497342069792_59` with your new name in current file text also, because java use same `class name` and `file name` together

Comment: So you are suggesting I do it manually ? there is no way to specify an argument is the python command itself ?

Comment: I think you can open current file in python and do simple replace

Comment: You can open `.java` file in any text editor, so you can try it.